# Ignoring commas within fields using AWK when there are multiple field separators

Tags: regex, csv, awk

I want to parse CSV records like the one below with `awk` or `gawk`.

The fields are separated by commas but the last field (`$6`) is special because it really consists of subfields. These subfields are separated by # as the field separator (or, to be precise, ". # ").  This in itself is not a problem: I can use `awk -F'(,)|(. # )'` to set alternative field separators.

However, there are stray commas in this last field as well that need to be ignored.

Is there a way to solve this with `awk`, perhaps using FPAT?

Sample record:

```
  "http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/3befa3c3-a9af-4dac-baa2-92e95cb6e3ab","http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/3befa3c3-a9af-4dac-baa2-92e95cb6e3ab.0002","EU:C:1985:443","61984CJ0239","Gerlach","Judgment of the Court (Third Chamber) of 24 October 1985. # Gerlach & Co. BV, Internationale Expeditie, v Minister van Economische Zaken. # Reference for a preliminary ruling: College van Beroep voor het Bedrijfsleven - Netherlands. # Article 41 ECSC - Anti-dumping duties. # Case 239/84."
```

Comment: Doesn't work because when `awk` encounters a comma that's the end of the field. E.g. in the sample record, there will only be two subfields in $6 and then the comma after BV means there's suddenly a $7 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `FPAT` feature in `gnu-awk`, you may be able to do this. We use `FPAT` to match all double quoted fields or comma separated fields. Finally we split on last field using `/\. # /` regex pattern.

```sh
s='"http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/3befa3c3-a9af-4dac-baa2-92e95cb6e3ab","http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/3befa3c3-a9af-4dac-baa2-92e95cb6e3ab.0002","EU:C:1985:443","61984CJ0239","Gerlach","Judgment of the Court (Third Chamber) of 24 October 1985. # Gerlach & Co. BV, Internationale Expeditie, v Minister van Economische Zaken. # Reference for a preliminary ruling: College van Beroep voor het Bedrijfsleven - Netherlands. # Article 41 ECSC - Anti-dumping duties. # Case 239/84."'

awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]+' '{
   # loop through all fields except last one
   for (i=1; i<NF; ++i)
      print i, $i
   # split last field using /\. # / regex and print each token
   for (j=1; j<split($NF, a, /\. # /); ++j)
      print i+j-1, a[j]
}' <<< "$s"

1 "http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/3befa3c3-a9af-4dac-baa2-92e95cb6e3ab"
2 "http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/3befa3c3-a9af-4dac-baa2-92e95cb6e3ab.0002"
3 "EU:C:1985:443"
4 "61984CJ0239"
5 "Gerlach"
6 "Judgment of the Court (Third Chamber) of 24 October 1985
7 Gerlach & Co. BV, Internationale Expeditie, v Minister van Economische Zaken
8 Reference for a preliminary ruling: College van Beroep voor het Bedrijfsleven - Netherlands
9 Article 41 ECSC - Anti-dumping duties
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close except in $6 I need the split to happen at the `. # ` and *not* at the comma after the word "BV", nor at the comma after the word "Expeditie". So $7 should come out as "Gerlach & Co. BV, Internationale Expeditie,  v Minister van Economische Zaken".

Comment: That was quick!  However, I still get the same result. I'm on macOS GNU awk 5.1.0

Comment: I am also on macOS using `GNU Awk 5.1.0`. Can you show your command and output in question?

Comment: I stand corrected, it does work now! Could you add a line of explanation, particularly how you use `NF`?

Comment: I have added comments in my answer

Comment: @Timothy Roes dont forget to upvote the answer