# Does awk FPAT not work within AppleScript do shell script?

Tags: shell, awk, escaping, applescript

I have an awk command that uses FPAT to ignore comma's in a CSV record (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66563519/ignoring-commas-within-fields-using-awk-when-there-are-multiple-field-separators)). This command works in the Terminal (default zsh shell):

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]+' 'NF==6 {split($NF, a, /\. # /)} NR!=1&&NF<=6 {print a[5],$5,$3,$4} ' input.txt
```

Sample record:

```
http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/3befa3c3-a9af-4dac-baa2-92e95cb6e3ab,http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/3befa3c3-a9af-4dac-baa2-92e95cb6e3ab.0002,ECLI:EU:C:1985:443,61984CJ0239,Gerlach,"Judgment of the Court (Third Chamber) of 24 October 1985. # Gerlach & Co. BV, Internationale Expeditie, v Minister van Economische Zaken. # Reference for a preliminary ruling: College van Beroep voor het Bedrijfsleven - Netherlands. # Article 41 ECSC - Anti-dumping duties. # Case 239/84."
```

However, it does not work in my AppleScript, where I have entered it (with escaping) like this.

```
set r1 to do shell script "awk -v FPAT='\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]+' '{print a[5],$5,$3,$4
}' <<<" & quoted form of theInput
```

With this command, awk still treats a space as the field delimiter. In other words, it appears to ignore the `FPAT` completely. This is very clear when one replaces the `print` statement with a simple `print $1`.

I have tested the command in the Terminal with the sh shell (which the do shell script command uses by default) and this still works perfectly so that does not seem to be the problem.

Could it be the awk version? When I do the following in the command line `awk -W version`
the output is: `GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)`

Comment: The default `PATH` passed to a `do shell script` _command_ is `"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"` and anything called that is not within that path, the _fully qualified pathname_ needs to be used or include a `PATH` _statement_ as a _compound command_, i.e. the actual `PARH=$PATH`, where `$PATH` is the actual `PATH` followed by a `;` and the additional _commands_.

Comment: Instead of `awk` use `gawk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain, but the problem could be that when you're running the shell script in the AppleScript, it doesn't know where `awk` is. (The shell environment inside an AppleScript is not the same as the user's.)

Try this one-liner in an AppleScript:

`do shell script "awk -W version"`

If that returns nothing, go back to your terminal and enter `which awk`. For me this returned: `/usr/local/bin/awk`

Returning to AppleScript:

`do shell script "/usr/local/bin/awk -W version"` returned the full version information.

So, my thesis is that using the full path to awk *may* solve your problem.

Comment: I love your approach to this problem

Comment: Thanks. It’s a shame the OP doesn’t come back with ... anything.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this did indeed fix it. I don't totally get why though. I know that, when you run `do shell script awk` in an AppleScript, this is run in the `sh` shell, not the default `zsh` shell. But does this mean that the `awk` is then a vanilla version that does not support FPAT, whereas the version of `awk` at `/urs/local/bin/awk` has been upgraded with e.g. `gawk` features?

Comment: Every question you could ever have about shell scripts in AppleScript is answered at: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html